# rails post form issue when using https

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, https

Following is my code, I am trying to post a form to a https site. I've googled many times with no luck.

```
post_params = {
               name: "Peter",
               age: "26",
               school: "St. Andrew Secondary"
             }
uri = URI.parse('https://www.somehttps.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri, "443")
http.use_ssl = true
http.post_form(uri, post_params)
```

But I always got:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `post_form' for #<Net::HTTP www.somehttps.com:443 open=false>)
```

Why is it so? Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try - Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, post_params)